# After being root, the custom .bashrc file no longer runs?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I modified my `.bashrc` file to customize my terminal.
I modified the else `PS1` statement to the one I needed and it works fine but when I login as root it switched back to the one it originally had.
How do I fix this?

Contents of my file are below:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

 uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turnedoff by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
     (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
     a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    #PS1='\n${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}"\u"  -->  Path:\w \n>>>'
    PS1='\n"\u"  -->  Path:\w \n>>>'
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

 If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

 enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: As you said, you modified *your* `.bashrc` file which is in your home directory, not root's `.bashrc` file which is in `/root` directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot Radu Radeanu. But it's not necessarily to be into the root directory you can do that also after logging in as root. AFter we log in as root, the .bashrc file in the home directory gets replaced by the file in the root directory so the changes can be made in the same directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with environmental variable and how you become root (`sudo`, `sudo -i`, `sudo -s`, and log in via console and ssh). You did not specify in your question how you logged in as root.

See:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=983645 or
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo or
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Solution (IMO): Copy the `.bashrc` you wish to use for root to `/root` directory and use `sudo -i` command to login as root.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, but the problem has been solved. The changes had to be made in the .bashrc file twice. ONce when you are a normal user and second when you are a root user. Once the changes have been saved it works for all.

Comment: You are actually modifying two different `.bashrc` files. One was for your regular user, one was for the root user. As @bodhi.zazen said, all you had to do was copy that one file from `~` to `/root`